# Sequential Number in Access Form Based on Field Selection

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hoping someone can assist here, I'm fairly new to SQL but yet the most experienced person in the office so this job has fallen to me.

I'm trying to build a form that will insert customer orders into production scheduling. The form allows users to select a machine from the machine list table, however what I need it to do after that is find the last job number for that specific machine and show the next sequential number in a text box; and that's where I'm stuck. The goal is that when the production user is adding an order to the database, by selecting their machine the next available job number is automatically populated. The information entered will be saved to a master scheduling table.

I've got a query built that pulls the entire list of machine and job combinations, as my goal was to build a macro that could search from that list, but so far I haven't gained any traction. Any help/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO, but I can tell you didn't read the "How do I ask a Question" section on this site before making your first post. You also didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site tour.  Please share your relevant code snippet getting to the solution as much as you can.  Suggest taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting again.

Comment: That is possible but how can we help you? We do not know your table structure, data type etc. Can you put screenshot of your form and table data (Sample data).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

My suggestion would be to create a table to hold the sequence numbers.  For the sake of this example, let's call it **ProdSeq**, which means *Production Sequences*.  As part of this table definition, I would use Data Macros (Access 2010 and up) in order to assign the sequences as records are added.  I would use a Unique index in order to ensure no duplicates are created.

**Table: ProdSeq**  (Field Definitions)

- `MachineID` (Number - Long) - References Machine ID in Machines Table
- `ProdSeq` (Number - Long) - Incremented for each machine
- `OrderID` (Number - Long) - References Order ID in Orders Table

**Indexes**
Under the **Design** ribbon tab when designing the `ProdSeq` table, click the *Indexes* button.

1. Create an Index called *UniqueKey*

   - Row 1: Index Name = `UniqueKey`, Field Name = `MachineID`
   - Row 2: Index Name = *Leave Blank*, Field Name = `ProdSequence`
2. Click on Row 1, Column 1 and set the following Index Properties:

   - `Primary = Yes`
   - `Unique = Yes`
   - `Ignore Nulls = No`

**Data Macros**
Under the **Design** ribbon tab when designing the `ProdSeq` table, click the **Create Data Macros** button, and then the **Before Change** button.  Enter the following data macro:  ([Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/raw/ePQjBBCR))

Create the **Before Change** data macro and set it as follows:

```
If [IsInsert] Then
    SetLocalVar
           Name  LatestProdSequence
     Expression  = 0

    Look Up A Record In   ProdSeq
        Where Condition   =[ProdSeqLookup].[MachineID]=[ProdSeq].[MachineID] And
                           [ProdSeqLookup].[LatestSeq] = True
                  Alias   ProdSeqLookup
       SetLocalVar
                 Name  LatestProdSequence
           Expression  =[ProdSeqLookup].[ProdSequence]
    SetField
           Name  ProdSeq.ProdSequence
          Value  = [LatestProdSequence]+1
    SetField
           Name  ProdSeq.LatestSeq
          Value  = True
End If
```

Pay special attention to the fact that only one SetLocalVar is within the LookUpRecord clause.  Use the collapse / expand (-/+) button on LookUpRecord to make sure.

Create the **After Insert** data macro and set it as follows:  ([Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/raw/78tzMs1E))

```
For Each Record In ProdSeq
    Where Condition  = [ProdSeqFlagFix].[MachineID]=[ProdSeq].[MachineID] And 
                       [ProdSeqFlagFix].[LatestSeq]=True And
                       [ProdSeqFlagFix].[ProdSequence]<>[ProdSeq].[ProdSequence]
    EditRecord
        SetField   
               Name  ProdSeqFlagFix.LatestSeq
              Value  = False
    End EditRecord
```

**Test it Out**
You can create this in a blank database in order to see what I am talking about.  You should be able to adapt it to your specific situation.

**Form**
On your form, when the user selects a machine and order, you can use VBA in order to check for an existing record in ProdSeq, and fetch the ID.  If no record exists, then you can create one, and then return the ProdSeq ID to the form.

Note:  Depending on your design, you may also need to create a Data Macro on the Schedules table.  Suppose someone creates a schedule with a specific machine and order and reserves a production slot.  Now assume they change the Order ID .. we have a production slot reserved in error.  So if this applies, you'll also need an AfterUpdate data macro on the Scheduling table that checks to see if [old].OrderID <> [Schedule].OrderID - and if they do differ, to remove the Production slot from the schedule table and the Prod Sequence table.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to add suggested value for job number when you add new record to the table. If so, you can use, for instance `DMax` function. Here is example of VBA code for this, it can be called when you add new record:

```
Me.MyTextBox = DMax("JobField", "JobsTable") + 1
```

I supposed that `JobField`, which contains job numbers has `Number` data type.
Also you can use this function inside any query as a calculated field.

Comment: Create the new number just when committing record to table to reduce risk of multiple users getting the same calculated number. Or create the new number and immediately commit new record to table, then user completes data entry but should not be allowed to abort new record.