# Incrementally update adjacent column when entering data into column

Tags: excel, ms-access, increment

Not sure if this would be easier in excel or not but I am adding values to `Entry 1` that often do not follow numerical order. I want to be able to incrementally add 1 to `Entry 2`each time a new value is entered into `Entry 1`. The zeros are necessary placeholders but I need the cell, for example, to go from `0009` to `0010` when a new value is added to `Entry 1`.

| Entry 1 | Entry 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0001 |
| 40 | 0002 |
| 70 | 0003 |
| 80 | 0004 |
| ... | ... |
| 80 | 0010 |
| ... | ... |
| 50 | 0403 |

Comment: Access autonumber field normally increments, although gaps can occur if new record is aborted. If you don't want to risk gaps, will require code in order to save in table. Save a number and use formatting to show with leading zeros. Otherwise, build a report and use textbox RunningSum property to calculate increment. This is a common topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sequential Number in Access Form Based on Field Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192615/sequential-number-in-access-form-based-on-field-selection)

Comment: It would be easier in excel. In MS-Access query or report will also do same but `Auto Number` field in table will make your task easier.

Comment: use the format function to get the leading zeros to show in access.  format( "[Entry 1]", "0000")  in a table in design mode under general set [Entry 1] 's format property to 0000  This is not an official option but it works as format must wrap a call to the format function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above link does not answer my question. I am trying to do this in excel or access as the people I am designing this for do not have programming experience. If I understand correctly, the above is for mysql?

Comment: Why do you think it is for MySQL? Suggestions apply to MS Access. Autonumber field does not involve programming, nor does applying a format to that field. If you can't or won't use autonumber then the referenced link is applicable.

Comment: Relax @june7. I thought the link posted above was for MySQL because the question literally started with "Hoping someone can assist here, I'm fairly new to SQL." AutoNumber does not follow the correct syntax. It will incrementally add one for each row. I do not see a method to add leading zeros adding to 5 total digits which was part of the question.

Comment: SQL is a database query language used by many database platforms - MS Access is one as are MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle, etc. An autonumber field can be formatted to display with leading zeros. If you need to actually save the leading zeros (which I don't think is necessary), that requires code that saves value into a text field. Coding to generate a custom unique identifier is a common topic. The referenced link is only one such discussion.

Comment: Here is another https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the feedback. I ended up going with Google Sheets to solve my issue. Adding:

```
=ArrayFormula( {"RDU#"; if( row(C2:C) - iferror( vlookup( row(B2:B) , if( len(B2:B) , iferror(1/0) , row(B2:B) ) , 1 ) , 1 ) , row(C2:C) - iferror( vlookup( row(B2:B) , if(len(B2:B) , iferror(1/0) , row(B2:B) ) , 1 ) , 1 ) , ) } )
```

To a column enabled me to generate auto numbers in column C with each new entry in column B. I was able to format the column with a custom number format of `00000`, which is defined as zero. Furthermore, I can integrate a Google Form for my constituents to enter in data, and everything can be adequately formatted on the Sheet.